# How to Assign Certain Data to Specific Areas in R Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm making a Leaflet map in R and I want to assign certain data to the specific areas. Right now I'm using a placeholder just to try and figure it out but I'm not having luck. I have certain data from an excel file that I want to assign to certain counties. How would I go about that?

```
library(maptools)
library(leaflet)
library(rjson)
library(magrittr)
library(sf)
library(xlsx)



## reads in the JSON data of all counties in USA 
counties <- sf::read_sf("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json")

## selects kansas and missouri county lines
kscounties<-counties[counties$STATE=="20",]
mocounties<-counties[counties$STATE=="29",]


## variable containing all kansas and missouricounty names
kscountynames<-kscounties$NAME
mocountynames<-mocounties$NAME


## combines both counties
bothcounties<-rbind(kscounties,mocounties)
bothcountynames<-c(kscountynames,mocountynames)




## color pallette 
pal<-colorNumeric("viridis",NULL)

## placeholder
percent=c(1:100)


## creates leaflet of kansas and missouri counties
leaflet(bothcounties) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.3, fillOpacity = 1,
    fillColor = ~pal(percent),
    label = ~paste(bothcountynames, "\n", formatC(percent, big.mark = ",")
                    )) %>% 

      setView(-98.4,38.5,zoom=6) %>% 
      addLegend(position="bottomright",pal = pal, values = percent, opacity = 1.0,title="Percent") %>% 
  addLayersControl(position="topleft",
                   baseGroups = c("1","2"),
               overlayGroups=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a separate dataframe containing the data in question and refer to it when plotting. You just have to be careful to ensure the order of counties in the dataframe matches the order of counties in the geo-data. The county names you're already extracting should work as a 'key' to match that order.

From your code above, change the #placeholder part to..

```
data_to_plot <- data.frame("NAME"=bothcountynames,"data"=###YOURDATA_IN_CORRECT_ORDER###))
```

..with the data you want to plot. You could also just set-up a single-column dataframe with the names and then do a merge/join as it may be an easier way to maintain the required order.

In the leaflet call, put `fillColor = pal(data_to_plot$data)`. The `~` basically won't be necessary if the data you're referencing is stored in a separate object.